# Setting up Raspberry Pi 3 with 7" touchscreen

Tags: pi-3, setup, lcd

I recently purchased a 7" touchscreen LCD with a driver board and I'm trying to figure out how to get it hooked up to my Raspberry Pi 3. 
Here's the driver board and my Pi:
[image: driver board]
[image]
My main questions are as follows:

My expectation here is that I hook the LCD to the driver board via the ribbon cable, then the driver board to the Pi via an HDMI cable. There does not seem to be any way to hook up the LCD to the Pi directly. Does this seem correct?

Do I need to supply the LCD driver board with its own power? Or is there a way to set it up such that it gets power from the Pi?

What the hell is this thing for (it came with the LCD and the driver board )?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.- connect the ribbon from display to driver board
2.- connect HDMI cable from driver board to RPI3
3.- connect driver board to power
4.- turn on the screen
5.- change the source to HDMI(in the button panel)

its really easy to connect that, kind of screens, I have one and it works
like charm.

Comment: Rad, thanks for confirming my intuition. One more thing, is there any (easy) way to get the LCD to use the Pi's power source as a power source? Or will I need to plug two things into a wall to get this to work?

Comment: I suggest you to have two energy sources, you can power the display from RPI3 but it will consume much more energy, I created my own screen with some lithium batteries and the circuit of a cheap power bank